# Posting Object to Api using Vue.js and Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to post a new object to my api array using axios and Vue.js. I'm trying to add the functionality to add a new object and display it on the timeline. I can see that when I post a new title I get a console.log of the object but it is not added to the correct array from the api, there is no new id associated with the new object.

Index.html

```
<body>
<div id="app">

    <template>
        <form @submit.prevent>   
        <input type="text" v-model="postBody"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" @click="postPost()">Post Title</button>
      </form>
        <ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
          <li v-for="error of errors">
            {{error.message}}
          </li>
        </ul>
    </template>

    <br>

    <!-- <p>{{ status }}</p> -->

  <template v-for="(results, index) in result">

      <div  class="card" style="width: 20rem; display:inline-block;">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>{{ results.id }}</p>
         <p>{{ results.title }}</p>
         <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-toggle="modal" v-on:submit.prevent="deleteData(index)" @click="deleteData(results, index) in result">Delete</button> -->

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-toggle="modal" @click="deleteData(results, index)">Delete</button>

     <h1> {{ results.comments}} </h1>

        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

</div>
</body>
```

Main.js

```
  var vm = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    result: '',
    title: '',
    data: '',
    postBody: '',
    User: { title: '' },
    errors: []
  },

  created: function(){
    this.getResult();
  },

  methods: {

    getResult: function() {
      // this.results = 'Loading...';
      axios.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/shaneogrady/json/db')
      .then(response => {
        // console.log(response.data);
        this.result = response.data.posts;
        console.log(this.result);
      });
    },

    deleteData: function(result, id) {
      axios.delete('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/shaneogrady/json/posts/' + result.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.result.splice(id, 1)
        console.log(this.result);
      });
    },

    postPost() {
      axios.post('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/shaneogrady/json/posts/', {
        // id: 4,
        // title: 'Shane',  
        body: this.postBody
      })
      .then(response => { console.log(response.data); this.result.push(response.data) })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
    }

  }
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure your backend handles the post request, and adds to the db? It seems to just stay pending.

Comment: It should be, but even at that the new object does not get assigned an id. I'm not sure why

Comment: It's a funny thing when you work with VueJS; I have this problem before and maybe it's a bug, but, removing the `<form>` and the `</form>` tags, fix this kind of issues.

Comment: Hi @Hackerman, thank you for your reply. But I'm still having the same issue. Ideally I just want to display the new object on the page once it is created but it doesn't seem to be working. Can't find any documentation online to fix the bug

Comment: Ok, you just missed a piece of code in your `postPost` method..replace it with this one `.then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.result.push(response.data)
      })`...I can post it as an answer if this is what you are trying to accomplish :)

Comment: @Hackerman, yes this is what I'm getting to, however the issue is still there. I can't delete the newly created objects as they are not assigned a unique id. I'm not sure why they are getting added to the array from the api

Comment: Looking at all the tests I did, it seems that you have a problem with the implementation of your post endpoint...I even try it with PostMan with the same result, the new post never gets created.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @submit.prevent on the form element

```
<div id="app">
        <form @submit.prevent>   
            <h4> Add Title</h4>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="pull-left"> Title </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title " v-model="User.title">
            </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" @click="postPost">Submit</button>
    </form>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

if u need to get results after creation of new object u just need to call ur `getResult` function inside `postPost` function

like this :

```
postPost() {
  axios.post('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/shaneogrady/json/posts/', {
    // id: 4,
    // title: 'Shane',  
    body: this.postBody
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.getResult();
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  })
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I can't call this function yet as the newly created object is not added to the array. So calling this function will remove the new object from the page and bring in the ones currently stored in the array. I'm trying to add the newly created object to the api. I can't delete the new objects as they don't have a unique id.